# Entity Framework 6 and Complex Types/ODATA REST Service

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, rest, odata

I've seen similar questions around this topic, but I haven't found a solution to my situation.  I've inherited a SQL Server database that uses a stored procedure to return a certain group of companies.  I'm trying to wrap an ODATA/REST service around the call so the data can be expose as XML or JSON.  Entity Framework seems to generate the stubs it needs; but when I call the service I get an error about complex types.

*The type 'xxxxxx' is mapped as a complex type. The Set method, DbSet objects, and DbEntityEntry objects can only be used with entity types, not complex types.*

Is there a way to have a result set return from a stored procedure NOT be a complex type?  This can't be this difficult...ugh

Appreciate any help/advice in advance.

Comment: Can you share mapping of the type?

Comment: Are you referring to the "results" class the EF generated?

Comment: The type returned by the stored procedure

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->public partial class result
{
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public int BusinessId { get; set; }
 public string BusinessName { get; set; }
 public string City { get; set; }
 public string State { get; set; }
 public string Phone { get; set; }
 public string WebSite { get; set; }
 public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
 public string Address1 { get; set; }
 public string County { get; set; }
 public string Zip { get; set; }
 public string ZipSuffix { get; set; }
 public string BusinessType { get; set; }
 public Nullable<short> YearEstablished { get; set; }
}

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404813/entity-framework-type-mapped-as-a-complex-type-error)

Comment: Thanks, my fields aren't virtual, but I'll try marking up the properties.  Thanks again for your reply.